# Камелота чи Камелоту?

Tags: правопис, граматика, іншомовні-слова, родовий-відмінок

Яке закінчення має слово «Камелот» у родовому відмінку?

Камелот — замок у британських легендах. Іменник чоловічого роду другої відміни. З одного боку, це — населений пункт, тому слово повинне мати закінчення «-а». А з іншого, Камелот — замок, а отже, він є спорудою, тож може закінчуватися на «-у».

У словниках цього слова не знайшов. Воно присутнє лише на одному сайті, де має закінчення «-у» в родовому відмінку, — [goroh.pp.ua](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Цікаве питання. І я не можу на нього відповісти.

1. З одного боку, у корпусі ГРАК-4 є лише *[Камелота](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac4&reload=&iquery=&queryselector=wordrow&lemma=&phrase=&word=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0&char=&cql=&default_attr=word&fc_lemword_window_type=both&fc_lemword_wsize=5&fc_lemword=&fc_lemword_type=all&usesubcorp=&fsca_doc.author=&fsca_doc.translator=&fsca_doc.authTrans=&fsca_doc.born=&fsca_doc.title=&fsca_doc.date=&fsca_doc.publisher=&fsca_doc.mediaName=&fsca_doc.locCode=&fsca_doc.region=)* (*Камелоту* не знаходжу навіть для давального відмінка).
2. З іншого боку, простий пошук в Інтернеті знаходить і вжитки з *-у*, наприклад:

   > Однією з таких спроб є згадана вище алано-сарматська гіпотеза, найдокладніше висвітлена у дослідженні «Від Скіфії до Камелоту» Скотта Литлтона й Лінди Малкор. //Геннадій Казакевич, «Кельти на землях України», [с. 17](//books.google.com/books?id=3EVGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4+%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%96%D1%84%D1%96%D1%97+%D0%B4%D0%BE+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83%22).

   Але це можна також інтерпретувати, мовляв, тут мається на увазі не конкретна фортеця, а радше метафорично натягається на цілий регіон (а регіони й великі просторові реалії — з *-у*).
3. «Правопис 2019» уточнює правила для населених пунктів. Тепер, згідно з [п. 2.1.1.2.к](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=89), закінчення *-а* мають лише населені пункти на *-ськ-/-цьк-/-ець-*, *-бург-/-град-/-город-/-піль-/-поль-/-мир-/-слав-*, *-ів-/-їв-/-ев-/-єв-/-ов-/-ин-/-ін-/-ач-/-ич-* та з наголосами на закінченні (*Бика́*), а інші, згідно з [п. 2.1.2.6](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=91), мають закінчення *-у* (*Амстерда́му, Го́мелю, Ліверпу́лю, Ло́ндону, Мадри́ду, Пари́жу, Чорно́билю*) або варіативне закінчення.
4. Аналогічне слово *Кодак* (це теж фортеця) корпус ГРАК-4 містіть і [з закінченням *-а*](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac4&reload=&iquery=&queryselector=wordrow&lemma=&phrase=&word=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0&char=&cql=&default_attr=word&fc_lemword_window_type=both&fc_lemword_wsize=5&fc_lemword=&fc_lemword_type=all&usesubcorp=&fsca_doc.author=&fsca_doc.translator=&fsca_doc.authTrans=&fsca_doc.born=&fsca_doc.title=&fsca_doc.date=&fsca_doc.publisher=&fsca_doc.mediaName=&fsca_doc.locCode=&fsca_doc.region=), і [з закінченням *-у*](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac4&reload=&iquery=&queryselector=wordrow&lemma=&phrase=&word=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83&char=&cql=&default_attr=word&fc_lemword_window_type=both&fc_lemword_wsize=5&fc_lemword=&fc_lemword_type=all&usesubcorp=&fsca_doc.author=&fsca_doc.translator=&fsca_doc.authTrans=&fsca_doc.born=&fsca_doc.title=&fsca_doc.date=&fsca_doc.publisher=&fsca_doc.mediaName=&fsca_doc.locCode=&fsca_doc.region=). Утім з *-а* частіше.
5. [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (а за ними й [Горох](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA)) містять *Кодак* із закінченням *-а*.

Я схиляюся до закінчення *-а* або варіативного закінчення.

Comment: Дякую за обґрунтовану відповідь!