# Родовий відмінок слова "пост" в значенні "допис"?

Tags: родовий-відмінок

На даний момент я схиляюсь до цієї версії:

> шукав пригожу ілюстрацію лісу для попереднього посту

Але "піст" в родовому має теж форму "посту". То хіба не правильніше для уникнення двозначності писати:

> шукав пригожу ілюстрацію лісу для попереднього поста

?

Поясніть мені чому ці правила закінчень -у, -а такі складні? Як так склалось історично і для чого це потрібно?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Як правильно - "елемента" чи "елементу"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2851/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83)

Comment: Також: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/427 , https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1350 , https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3900

Comment: @bytebuster, я не вважаю, що всі запитання на тему закінчень _-а/-у_ можна вважати дублікатами. Адже єдиних дієвих правил фактично немає (те, що в «Правописі», — неясне, приблизне й не завжди діє), тож фактично мовцю доводиться окремо вирішувати про кожне слово (за словниками, за частотами практичного вжитку абощо, але здебільшого не лише за § 82.2.1 у «Правописі»), тож відповідь про попереднє слово майже не допомагає відвідувачу у вирішенні про наступне слово. Спробуйте уявити себе на його місці: Ви питаєте про якусь специфічну ситуацію, а Вам кидають уже 10 разів бачене загальне правило.

Comment: @Sasha, я згоден, що дієвих правил щодо відмінювання таких слів — немає. А ті, що наявні, кожен вважає своїм обовʼязком уникати. :-) З іншого боку, ваш коментар значно виграв би, якби було якесь свідчення, що ОП таки побачив «10 разів бачене загальне правило» — якщо не 10 разів, то бодай один раз. Запитання такого свідчення не містить. А значить, правильний, на мою думку, підхід є **VTC** /duplicate (вказати на загальне правило) або **VTC** due to the lack of own research effort (вказати на загальне правило).

Comment: @Sasha, а от історична частина запитання, на відміну від першої загальної, є цілком самостійним, хорошим запитанням, НМД.

Comment: @bytebuster, Ви маєте рацію, що запитання не містить ознак того, що запитувач ознайомлений із загальними правилами. Але мій основний аргумент у тому, що ці правила неясні, приблизні й (у порівнянні зі словниками/узусом) другорядні — тому я не вважаю їх повною чи достатньою відповіддю на таке запитання, лише частковою (хоч, може, це й дуже важлива частина). Самі лише правила, які читачу незрозуміло як застосовувати, — це майже RTFM (але правила з власною інтерпретацією чи зі словниковою статтею — це вже добре, хоча це, знов-таки, буде відповіддю на конкретне питання, а не універсальною).

Comment: І закриття [запитання 3900](/q/3900) як дубліката, по-моєму, є великою [помилкою](/q/3900#comment8451_3900).

Comment: А хіба слово "пост" у цьому значенні - це звгалаі не росіянізм? Я завжди кажу "допис"
Допис - дописУ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово (у цьому значенні) у словниках не зафіксоване. І досліджень, як саме здебільшого його вживають де-факто, наскільки я знаю, теж ніхто не проводив.

Мені здається, більше підходить *-у*:

1. По-перше, більшість більш-менш близьких за значенням слів 2-ї відміни мають закінчення *-у*: *[ви́кладу](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9037&page=320)*, *[ві́дчиту](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14286&page=461)* (діалектне), *[доно́су](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23925&page=805)*, *[до́пису](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=24010&page=808)*, *[за́пису](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=31380&page=1021)*, *[о́пису](http://sum.in.ua/s/opys)*, *[пере́казу](http://sum.in.ua/s/perekaz)*, *[ра́порту](http://sum.in.ua/s/raport)*, *[рефера́ту](http://sum.in.ua/s/referat)*.

   Але: *[бю́летня](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6284&page=230)*.
2. По-друге, у [«Правописі» 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf), мені здається, це підходить під § 2.1.2.в (див. [с. 90](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=90)):

   > назви процесів, станів, властивостей, явищ суспільного життя, загальних понять: ана́лізу, бі́гу, ви́бою, ви́купу, ви́слову, відбо́ю, ві́дгуку, заробі́тку, зато́ру, за́пису, зву́ку (але як термін зву́ка), ідеа́лу, і́мпульсу, кло́поту, коло́квіуму, конфлі́кту, кро́ку, ле́ту (льо́ту), по́штовху, прибу́тку, приї́зду, прогре́су, ремо́нту, ру́ху, си́нтезу, сто́гону, су́мніву, у́спіху, хо́ду, шу́му, але ривка́, стрибка́, стусана́

   Але ці правила доволі неясні й приблизні, і трактувати їх можна по-різному.

Але, звісно, реальне закінчення визначатиме практичний ужиток, а не подібні слова в словниках чи нечіткі правила.

---

Омонімія виникатиме в будь-якому випадку:

- [піст](http://sum.in.ua/s/pist) (церковне поняття) — по́сту;
- [пост](http://sum.in.ua/s/ppst) (пункт спостереження; група осіб у пункті спостереження; посада) — поста́.

---

Ні для чого. Так склалося історично (чому так склалося історично, я, на жаль, не можу відповісти, недостатньо компетентний для цього). Мені здається, що таке розділення, мовляв, такі-то слова треба казати з *-а*, а такі-то з *-у*, нині майже нічим не корисне, а навпаки — шкодить, — але уявіть, як хтось перший почне казати все на *-а* (навіть ті слова, що твердо усталилися з *-у*) або все на *-у* (навіть ті слова, що твердо усталилися з *-а*) — це звучатиме дико. Імовірнішою мені здається картина, що колись усе настільки заплутається (або частина людей казатиме так — а інша інакше; або одні й ті самі люди використовуватимуть обидві форми), що обидва закінчення оголосять однаково дозволеними для всіх слів 2-ї відміни (як зараз, наприклад, у давальному відмінку формально дозволено *-у*, й *-ові*), — але ця картина існує лише в моїй уяві, і чи буде так, невідомо.

Comment: Пропоную запитання-дублікати все-таки закривати. Ваші відповіді ([один](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/5482/8), [два](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/5736/8)) завжди дуже добре висвітлюють конкретне слово, про яке запитує автор запитання (мені б бракувало терплячості, тут я знімаю шляпу), але багатьом іншим користувачам цілком достатньо посилання на Правопис і список категорій іменників II відміни, в яких у родовому відмінку ставиться `-а` versus `-у`.

Comment: @bytebuster, які ж це дублікати? Тут про _пост_, там про інші слова або загальну теорію. Якби моє запитання так закрили як дублікат (наприклад, я питаю як у VCL зробити вікно напівпрозорим, а мені кидають посилання на те, як у SWT зробити вікно напівпрозорим — або, ще гірше, на якісь неясні загальнотеоретичні міркування про те, як у сучасних менеджерах вікон створюється ефект напівпрозорості) — я б вирішив, що з мене знущаються.

Comment: @bytebuster, я згоден, що це запитання не дуже добре в тому плані, що воно «too broad» — тут і про конкретне слово, і «чому правила такі складні / для чого це потрібно» (мабуть, останнє підзапитання й «opinion based») — але це аж ніяк не дублікат!